# Max length of argument in MakeHeaders RFC2435

Tags: c, jpeg, rtp, rfc, mjpeg

In [RFC2435](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435) there is a function called `MakeHeaders`

```
/*
 *  Arguments:
 *    type, width, height: as supplied in RTP/JPEG header
 *    lqt, cqt: quantization tables as either derived from
 *         the Q field using MakeTables() or as specified
 *         in section 4.2.
 *    dri: restart interval in MCUs, or 0 if no restarts.
 *
 *    p: pointer to return area
 *
 *  Return value:
 *    The length of the generated headers.
 *
 *    Generate a frame and scan headers that can be prepended to the
 *    RTP/JPEG data payload to produce a JPEG compressed image in
 *    interchange format (except for possible trailing garbage and
 *    absence of an EOI marker to terminate the scan).
 */
int MakeHeaders(u_char *p, int type, int w, int h, u_char *lqt,
                u_char *cqt, u_short dri)
{
        u_char *start = p;

        /* convert from blocks to pixels */
        w <<= 3;
        h <<= 3;


        *p++ = 0xff;
        *p++ = 0xd8;            /* SOI */

        p = MakeQuantHeader(p, lqt, 0);
        p = MakeQuantHeader(p, cqt, 1);

        if (dri != 0)
                p = MakeDRIHeader(p, dri);

        *p++ = 0xff;
        *p++ = 0xc0;            /* SOF */
        *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
        *p++ = 17;              /* length lsb */
        *p++ = 8;               /* 8-bit precision */
        *p++ = h >> 8;          /* height msb */
        *p++ = h;               /* height lsb */
        *p++ = w >> 8;          /* width msb */
        *p++ = w;               /* wudth lsb */
        *p++ = 3;               /* number of components */
        *p++ = 0;               /* comp 0 */
        if (type == 0)
                *p++ = 0x21;    /* hsamp = 2, vsamp = 1 */
        else
                *p++ = 0x22;    /* hsamp = 2, vsamp = 2 */
        *p++ = 0;               /* quant table 0 */
        *p++ = 1;               /* comp 1 */
        *p++ = 0x11;            /* hsamp = 1, vsamp = 1 */
        *p++ = 1;               /* quant table 1 */
        *p++ = 2;               /* comp 2 */
        *p++ = 0x11;            /* hsamp = 1, vsamp = 1 */
        *p++ = 1;               /* quant table 1 */
        p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, lum_dc_codelens,
                              sizeof(lum_dc_codelens),
                              lum_dc_symbols,
                              sizeof(lum_dc_symbols), 0, 0);
        p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, lum_ac_codelens,
                              sizeof(lum_ac_codelens),
                              lum_ac_symbols,
                              sizeof(lum_ac_symbols), 0, 1);
        p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, chm_dc_codelens,
                              sizeof(chm_dc_codelens),
                              chm_dc_symbols,
                              sizeof(chm_dc_symbols), 1, 0);
        p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, chm_ac_codelens,
                              sizeof(chm_ac_codelens),
                              chm_ac_symbols,
                              sizeof(chm_ac_symbols), 1, 1);

        *p++ = 0xff;
        *p++ = 0xda;            /* SOS */
        *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
        *p++ = 12;              /* length lsb */
        *p++ = 3;               /* 3 components */
        *p++ = 0;               /* comp 0 */
        *p++ = 0;               /* huffman table 0 */
        *p++ = 1;               /* comp 1 */
        *p++ = 0x11;            /* huffman table 1 */
        *p++ = 2;               /* comp 2 */
        *p++ = 0x11;            /* huffman table 1 */
        *p++ = 0;               /* first DCT coeff */
        *p++ = 63;              /* last DCT coeff */
        *p++ = 0;               /* sucessive approx. */

        return (p - start);
};
```

How can I know what is the length of argument `u_char *p` ?

Comment: At first sight it is an simple example to illustrate the RFC. As such, the proposed code is as simple as possible. For a robust application, the proposed interface is weak as you don't force the caller of the function to pass the lenght of the memory aread pointer by "p". For a real application, you should add a "size" parameter for the memory area and check inside the function that you are not going over the limits or modify the function to make dynamic allocation to increase the size of the buffer according to the needs (malloc/realloc).

Comment: @RachidK. you right , but I using that algorithm to implement that , so how can I know that maximum size of `u_char *p` that looks const

Comment: With such an interface you can't know which size it is. Only the caller of this function knows it : the one which pass the "p" parameter.